# compare items in tableView with selected items

Tags: arrays, swift

I am fetching items from an api, and I want to compare them with my array

ex:  fetched `items = [1,2,3,4]`

I want to find items `[1,2]`.

And want to set checkmark on the `tableView`

in `cellForRowAt()`

I have used this

```
if(alreadySelectedItems.count != 0) {
        if(dataModel.contains(alreadySelectedItems[indexPath.row])){
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
```

and

```
if(alreadySelectedItems.count != 0) {
        if(dataModel[indexPath.row] == alreadySelectedItems[indexPath.row]) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
```

Where `dataModel` is list of items from the api and `alreadySelecteditems` are my `selectedItems`

I am getting

> Error: indexOut of range

here is my tableView Extension functions

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return dataModel.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CheckableTableViewCell
    cell.dataModel = dataModel[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    selectedItems.append(dataModel[indexPath.row])

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    selectedItems.removeObject(object: dataModel[indexPath.row])
}
```

and cell is :

```
class CheckableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var dataModel : String?
    {
        didSet
        {
            guard let model = dataModel else {return}
            textLabel?.text = model
        }
    }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        self.tintColor = .primaryColor
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with all your tableView methods?

Comment: done please check

Comment: Do you have a numberOfSections function?

Comment: no , only number of items

Comment: try adding this function with return 1. Also can you see the tableView rows or not?Check @PGDev answer i think is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're checking the existence of `selectedItems[indexPath.row]` in the `dataModel`, i.e.

```
dataModel.contains(selectedItems[indexPath.row])
```

Instead it must be the other way round, i.e.

```
selectedItems.contains(dataModel[indexPath.row])
```

This is the reason it is giving `Index Out of Bounds` exception.

Simply change the definition of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` to,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CheckableTableViewCell
    let dataModel = self.dataModel[indexPath.row]
    cell.dataModel = dataModel
    cell.accessoryType = self.selectedItems.contains(dataModel) ? .checkmark : .none //here..........
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: nope , what i am doing is , i am coming to a view calling api appending strings in my array , then using this array i am creating tableView and appending selected items in different arrray , now when dismissing the view i am taking these selectedItems with me to previous view now user thinks and want to change his selections so on didSelect i am taking those selected arrays to my view where i selected them again api is called and tableView is populated but now i have some items which i previously selected so i want those selections appear on the screen . as a checkmarks like i selected them

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension to find same elements if your arrays

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func sameElements(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        let firstSet = Set(self)
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        return Array(firstSet.intersection(otherSet))
    }
}
```